# Post-apocalyptic books series set in USA where people live in underground silos

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

The storyline is a series of 6 or 7 books that I probably read in the late 70s (but never finished reading the series)

In this post-apocalyptic world humanity (in the USA at least) is reduced to living in large underground silos that have a central, open airshaft, and are scattered around the country. The deeper your accommodations are in the silo, the more prestigious they are.  There is trade between each silo via an overland road train that is armored against the mutants who live on the surface, and has weapons such as a catapult launched, solar electric powered plane.

One of first scenes in the first book is where the main protagonist, a young man, is flying one of the planes inside a silo and attempting to shoot at randomly generated targets in a flight test.  He completes this test perfectly due his preternaturally good reflexes that sets him above all other pilots.  As a result he is assigned to fly support for one of these road trains.

As the books progress he becomes disillusioned with his "modern" society and starts to side with the mutants.  It may have been alluded that while he looked like a "normal" person, that he actually came from mutant heritage - which is the basis for his amazing reflexes.  And at one point he learnt/was taught how to apply makeup on his face so he could pass for a mutant.

In later books he visits places like Detroit(?) where he encounters mutants wearing Japanese style masks.  But the city name used in the books was split into multiple words that related to the tribes that controlled the area.  There was also a scene where a group of operatives were sent to capture him (or infiltrate the mutants), and one of the operatives was a woman who had a radio concealed in a fake pregnancy bump. The protagonist ends up killing them.

And from a quick google, it is definitely not Wool.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yep, that is the series.  So this is a dupe.

Comment: I recognised it instantly from your description. All dedicated SF geeks have read The Amtrak Wars :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie there's at least one who hasn't :) I grew weary of post-apocalyptic novels in the 1970s and started avoiding them like, erm, the plague.